# Why can't I run dev dependencies after `pipenv install --dev`?

Tags: python, pipenv

My project has `django-heroku` in its Pipfile as a `package`.

`django-heroku` has `gunicorn` in its Pipfile as a `dev-package`. See: https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/Pipfile

I would expect that after running `pipenv install --dev` in my project, I could then run `pipenv run gunicorn`.

But it throws the following error:

`Error: the command gunicorn could not be found within PATH or Pipfile's [scripts].`

If dev dependencies aren't available, what's the point of `install --dev`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One answer is that the "dev dependencies" of package X are the packages someone would need if they were developing (as opposed to using) package X.

> I would expect that after running pipenv install --dev in my project, ...

If you use `pipenv install --dev` in *your project*, pipenv should install all the packages that are required to develop your project.

If it recursively installed all dev dependencies all the way down, it might pull in Python profiling packages, test runners, etc., that other packages need for development.  Those wouldn't necessarily be appropriate for someone developing *your* project.

As an example, if my project listed `pytest` as a dev dependency , I would be unhappy in `pipenv` installed `nose`, which could be listed as an dev depenedency in some other, out-of-date package.

If developers of your package need `gunicorn`, you should list it explicitly as a dev dependency of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Pipfile` you've linked to is only relevant to the *development* of this package.

However when the package is *installed*, it usually relies on [`setup.py`](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/v0.3.0/setup.py#L23):

```
REQUIRED = [
    'dj-database-url>=0.5.0', 'whitenoise', 'psycopg2', 'django'
]
```

As you can see, `gunicorn` is missing.